# application of FTC to find a function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

this is what written in my worksheet:

find a function$"f(t)"$ and a number $"a"$ such that

$$6 + \int_{a}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \ dt = 2\sqrt{x}$$

so i change things a bit

$$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \ dt = 2\sqrt{x} - 6$$ and differentiating both sides left with respect of $x$ using FTC on LHS and normal differential at RHS and get

$$\frac{f(x)}{x^2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

then i take

$f(x)=x^\frac{3}{2}$ and $f(t)=t^\frac{3}{2}$ then i take $a=9$ to completing the equation. but i don't know whether this right or not since worksheet doesn't provide answers , so i would thankful if someone could tell me how

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: @KaboMurphy thank you for checking it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly found the function $f(t)$ and the number $a$. You can check your answer by evaluating $f(t)=t^{3/2}$ and $a=9$

$$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t^2} \ dt=\int_{9}^{x}\frac{t^{3/2}}{t^2}\ dt =\int_{9}^{x}\frac{1}{t^{1/2}}\ dt= \Big[2\sqrt{t}\Big]_9^x=2\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{9}=2\sqrt{x}-6$$